# how to see nat table for virbr0?

Tags: 12.04

How can I check the nat table for virbr0? I can see pings heading to the Host ip, but I get destination host unreachable.

```
ping 192.168.10.151
PING 192.168.10.151 (192.168.10.151) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.10.100 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable


192.168.10.100 host (br0 interface)
192.168.10.151 guest

virbr0 ip: 192.168.11.149
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo iptables --table nat --list --numeric --verbose
```

or in its short form:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -L -nv
```

- `--table nat` is key: it lists the NAT table.
- `--list` is the obvious listing command.
- `--numeric` is probably needed to speed it up as it would otherwise do reverse lookups for each addresses.
- `--verbose` is the obvious "I want all output" option.

---

Example output:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -L -nv
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 22 packets, 6050 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 12 packets, 2994 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 5190 packets, 340K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 5164 packets, 337K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination             
    0     0 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
    8   854 MASQUERADE  udp  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
    1    40 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24
```